# Interesting problem notices in php imagecolorallocate. I am stuck and need valuable suggestions

Tags: php, colors, gd

Here are two pieces of code. First I try to allocate an colour to the image and save the image

```
<?php $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream'); 
  $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 143, 198, 269);
  {
    for ($j=0; $j<200; $j++)
    {       

    imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $color);

    }

     }              

     $filename = 'test.png';

     imagepng($im, $filename);

      ?>
```

In second piece I read the saved image and print the allocated color.

```
    <?php

    $filename = 'test.png';

    $im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 1, 1);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

    echo "allocated color: r =".$r."g =".$g."b =".$b;


    ?>
```

It prints : allocated color: r =143 g =199 b =13
Hence the allocated color is completely different from the one which I wanted. Now How do I deal with this. Any suggestions please.

Comment: If you found the solution, post what the solution is as an answer then mark it as accepted. You never know, someone else might have the same problem and it'd be useful to see a solution. There's no need to say sorry for posting, everyone is learning :)

Comment: that's quite funny. I tried several different things. Apart from the fact that your first code snippet isn't complete (or wrong) - because `$i` is not set - I also get the wrong values. I read that `imagecolorsforindex()` works better for PNG files - but I didn't get a better result either. When I've time I'll inspect that a little deeper.

Comment: Emh... I tried another few minutes with different filetypes (jpg, gif, ...) until I checked that your value for the `blue` color is not really "allowed". `269 > 255`! And ... "make an educated guess" - `269 - 256` = `**13**`. So - the processing itself is okay!